# Is it possible to have an extension class that works for other projects too?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

In `C#` when we write an extension class it uses the `this` keyword to say that this extension method works on the objects of this namespace.

Now what if I want to write an extension class which works on other projects too? For example let's say my *Controls* project has this class and my *Main* project which has a reference to Controls porject want to call the extension methods, is it possible at all? Or I should rewrite the class in the Main project too?

Comment: As long as your Control project is compiling and you have reference of Control project in your Main project, it should work, just like all the other classes. Just make sure you specify the namespace of extension class in using directive, where ever you are using it. Visual studio will not provide you the option to resolve extension methods.

Comment: One of the most common uses of extension methods is for cross-assembly extensions: otherwise you could just *edit the original code*. So yes, this will work just fine.

Comment: extensions are based on namespace, and importing... so if you extend, for example, the TreeView class, and then place that extension in a class, you will be able to use it anywhere within any project, as long as you include this class (or library if you built it like that) in the project ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't duplicate the methods; what you want is entirely possible. If your classes and their extensions are both declared in the Controls project you can access the extension methods in Main. You just have to remember to add a using statement to include the namespace where the extension methods are declared.

Comment: Yeah it was just the matter of using, I was relying on Visual Studio's intellisence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible.
I guess you are missing the appropriate using statements as Visual Studio does not provide any guidence on that.

I tend to put the extensions into the same namespace as the type I am extending so if the types namespace is used the extension is also visible.
E.g. extensions for `String` are in the `System` namespace not `MyApp.Something.Extensions`.
This is especially usefull if other developers should use them as they may never know of their existence otherwise.